# PHP Mail Form Not Sending Mail

Tags: php

I have a PHP mail form that is not sending mail. The script runs as it should for the user; takes them to the "Thank you!" page, but mail never comes to the email address it was supposed to go to. How can I go about fixing this issue? I have tried to solve it via other threads here on stackoverflow, but my issue is unique.

PHP

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "the_email@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Enter a subject");
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://www.thewebsite.com/thankyou.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you using wordpress?

Comment: So `john.doe@example.com` is not a valid email? https://regex101.com/r/OvRqyw/1

Comment: @Sreejith BS, no I am using this for a website I built myself. HTML, CSS, and JavaScript I am familiar with, but PHP I am not. :)

Comment: If you are running this code on a local server (i.e your computer for development purposes) it wont send the email to the recipient.

Comment: @Sreejith BS Is there a way I can send mail via the local server? I have an SMTP server setup on here that seems to be running; just checked it via terminal again to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The function mail returns a boolean. As documentation says, ...

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

So, ... store mail returned value to check if something went wrong.

```
$mailSent = mail(...);
if (!$mailSent) {
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

And if you are using windows, ... you have to know that

> when PHP is talking to a SMTP server directly, if a full stop is found
>   on the start of a line, it is removed. To counter-act this, replace
>   these occurrences with a double dot.

```
<?php
$text = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $text);
?>
```

Another final check to do is, ... have you smtp server installed in the machine that runs the script? If not install one. Depending on which OS, or *AMP like system you have, may be possible that something is missing: smtp could be abstent. It is possibile that this code works in production but not in your personal computer.

Comment: Thank you for the information, my SMTP server is working on my machine from how I was instructed to check anyway. I'm using OS X 10.6.8 for the server machine; old, I know... but it usually gets the job done. @sensorario

Comment: I would strongly urge you not too use PHP's mail() method - it is not secure or safe to use.  See here for more: https://blog.ripstech.com/2017/why-mail-is-dangerous-in-php/